# why in this sql, function AVG() must be in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT NAME，SALARY
FROM STAFF
WHERE SALARY>(SELECT AVG(SALARY) FROM SFAFF)
AND YEARS < (SELECT AVG(YEARS) FROM STAFF)
```

why in this sql, function AVG must be in subquery?
why the sql below is wrong?

```
SELECT NAME，SALARY
FROM STAFF
WHERE SALARY>AVG(SALARY)
AND YEARS < AVG(YEARS)
```

Comment: The WHERE clause evaluates one row at the time.

Answer (score 3):

`AVG` and other aggregate functions work on sets of data. The `WHERE` clause does not have access to the entire set, only to data for the row it is operating on. You may go for `having` clause after the `group by`, while dealing with data sets.

Comment: got it.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the GROUP BY clause. Every aggregate functions needs a GROUP BY in order to function properly.

```
SELECT  NAME，SALARY
FROM    STAFF
WHERE   SALARY > (
                    SELECT  AVG(SALARY)
                    FROM    SFAFF
                    GROUP BY [some_unique_value]
                    )
        AND YEARS < (
                        SELECT  AVG(YEARS)
                        FROM    STAFF
                        GROUP BY [some_unique_value]
                    )
```

Comment: I didn't use GROUP BY because it's for the whole table